# Graddle error when adding firebase to flutter

Tags: flutter

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

**The flutter projects works fine without firebase but when I add firebase it makes this error**

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should update gms google service. Could you try this and let me know if it worked for you

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```